# Rails app - populating the db cache and keeping it populated

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5.2 app running on Ubuntu that works with a large MySQL database with over 50 million records.

Users perform searches on the database. Specific searches are performed in an acceptable timeframe.

However, the default is a complete wildcard search to return the first, say, 50 records, sorted (ordered) on one or more of the fields.

The default wildcard search can take quite a while, but once performed, the results are cached, repeats of the wildcard search are very fast.

Often the results remain cached, but sometimes the cache gets flushed, and the search has to be performed again which takes a long time again.  The cache has always been flushed in the morning, which I attribute to the server / database being backed up overnight, or the cloud server instance being somehow flushed.

OK, I thought, I'll just run a cronjob that runs regularly (hourly) and re-populate the cache.  So that's what I do, and I am careful to actually perform the search (not just create an Active Record Query that is not actually performed).

The cronjob invokes a method in the Model that performs the database query (and throws away the result).  I can see from the logging that the search is performed.

Unfortunately, this attempt to populate the cache does not seem to benefit the HTTP RESTful API that pulls the same data. The first wildcard queries in a while always take a long time, even if a cronjob populate cache task has run recently.  However, again, once a RESTful API search has completed, subsequent repeats of that same query return the cached response very quickly.

Maybe the RESTful query is not recognised as being the same search as performed in the cronjob?

Suggestions as to how I can populate the cache, and keep it populated appreciated.

**UPDATE**

SQL generated by Rails for query,

```
SELECT  `products`.*
    FROM  `products`
    WHERE  `products`.`category` = 0
      AND  `products`.`available` = TRUE
    ORDER BY  LENGTH(prefix) ASC,
              LENGTH(numbers) ASC,
              LENGTH(suffix) ASC,
              `products`.`prefix` ASC,
              `products`.`numbers` ASC,
              `products`.`suffix` ASC
    LIMIT  20 OFFSET 0
```

Relevant part of schema,

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category"
    t.string "prefix"
    t.string "numbers"
    t.string "suffix"
    t.boolean "available", default: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "open_sale", default: false
    t.index ["category", "prefix", "numbers", "suffix"], name: "index_products_category_prefix_numbers_suffix"
  end
```

Comment: Please show us the SQL involved, plus the schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: @RickJames Added as requested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's one single specific query I would just consider that a special case and use rails' cache for that one.

```rb
def index
  @records =
    if condition_to_detect_that_wildcard_search
      Rails.cache.fetch("some_cache_key", expires_in: 1.month) do
        do the query
      end
    else
      do the query
    end
end
```

You can use some globally accessible variable if you need to eventually change the cached values.

Comment: @arieljoud Very interesting, I'll looking into that and report back, thank you.

Comment: @arieljoud This was really helpful and interesting, but I tried it and it didn't help.  Thanks for the suggestion and insight though.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I didn't totally solve the issue of the first load of the day taking a long time, but I certainly learned a lot about Rails caching.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to be specific on the cahe that you are talking about. There’s buffer cache in your sql db which means when you perform a query, the data pages that are needed to be scanned will will be paged in to your memory from the disk. Then in the subsequent query, assuming the cached page is still in memory, the query time would be short.

You mentioned that you are hitting the search query on hourly basis, that wont be always helpful as the cached data page might be evicted to give way for other data page required by subsequent query. If this happens, when the next search query happens, your sql db will incurred disk IO for those pages in and it will be slow.

One way of solving this is that you still run the cron but this time you need to load the result in your cache store like Redis.

```
def reload_cached_search
  Rails.cache.write(“cache-key”, search_query_result)
end
```

This approach is similar to the above answer but you will have better control as you are refreshing the cache actively on your end and your user search will be quite unlikely to invoke a db query.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I didn't totally solve the issue of the first load of the day taking a long time, but I certainly learned a lot about Rails caching.

Answer (score 1):

That query needs an index *starting with* `category, available` (in either order).  But more than that, if you could get rid of the `LENGTH(..)` parts of the `ORDER BY`, then this would allow a superior index, thereby eliminating any need for caching:

```
INDEX(category, available, prefix, numbers, suffix)
```

Probably the current setup *must* scan the *entire table* every time.  With my suggestions,

```
WHERE  `products`.`category` = 0
  AND  `products`.`available` = TRUE
ORDER BY  `products`.`prefix` ASC,
          `products`.`numbers` ASC,
          `products`.`suffix` ASC
LIMIT  20 OFFSET 0
```

would touch only 20 rows.

I need to see an example, *in SQL, not in Rails*, of the "wildcard" problem.  With that, I may be able to suggest an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I didn't totally solve the issue of the first load of the day taking a long time, but I certainly learned a lot about Rails caching.